# Почему Vue global EventBus не работают в моем проекте

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Я использую vue js в laravel, мне нужно использовать шину глобальных событий. Я создал event-bus.js и импортирую его туда, где мне нужно его использовать; когда я нажимаю, генерируются события, но от слушателя не происходит никаких реакций. Я перепробовал все, но это не работает. Пожалуйста, помогите мне, я работаю в течение 3 дней

Я пытался создать eventBus в app.js, но это тоже не помогло

My EditDiscountComponent

```
import { EventBus } from "../../../event-bus";

editDiscount () {
        const data = {
          discount_id: this.discountData.discount_id,
          status: this.discountData.status,
          type: this.discountData.type,
          percentage:this.discountData.percentage,
          amount:this.discountData.amount,
        };

        EventBus.$emit('update-discount', data);

         this.languages.forEach(lang => {
              if (lang.code && this.discountData[lang.code] !== undefined) {
                  data[lang.code] = this.discountData[lang.code];
              }
          });
        this.$store.dispatch(actions.EDIT_DISCOUNT, data)
          .then(res => {
            if (res && res.data.status) {

              // window.location.href = '/admin/discounts';

            } else {
              this.$store.commit(mutations.SET_SNACKBAR_SHOW, true);
              this.$store.commit(mutations.SET_SNACKBAR_TEXT, res.data.message);
            }
          }).catch(console.error);

      },
    },
```

My ProductCOmponent

```
import { EventBus } from "../../../event-bus";

 mounted() {
            EventBus.$on('update-discount', ($data) => {
                console.log($data);
            });
            this.getCategories();
            this.getProducts();
        },
```

Я попытался обратного вызова функции, используя другой метод, но безрезультатно, и я попытался этот слушатель в mount (), и это не помогло

Comment: Смонтирован ли компонент, который слушает событие? Может событие генерируется раньше, чем смонтирован компонент?

Comment: События генерируется, когда второй компонент уже смонтирован

Comment: На первый взгялд, такая запись, как у Вас, должна работать. Приведите воспроизводимый пример